# Clickonce full trust app update failing with TrustNotGrantedException on Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, clickonce

We have a winforms clickonce application in C# which is granted full trust and signed using a valid certificate.

The application runs fine and updates correctly on Windows XP, Windows 7. However, on a Windows 8 machine, it just fails to update. The application runs correctly though. However, the first update request to move up to a later version fails with: `System.Deployment.Application.TrustNotGrantedException`

The code failed after the call to `ApplicationDeployment::CheckForDetailedUpdate()` failed. Wondering why this could happen as the exact same code is running fine on all previous versions of Windows. Any help will be appreciated. Below is the relevant stack trace:

```
System.Deployment.Application.TrustNotGrantedException: User has refused to grant required permissions to the application.
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationTrust.RequestTrust(SubscriptionState subState, Boolean isShellVisible, Boolean isUpdate, ActivationContext actCtx, TrustManagerContext tmc)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrustCore(Boolean blocking, TrustParams tp)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrust(TrustParams trustParams)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CheckForDetailedUpdate(Boolean persistUpdateCheckResult)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CheckForDetailedUpdate()
```

Comment: Tried another Windows 8 laptop and the upgrade failed with the same error on that one too. Wondering what could go wrong with a full trust application. -Manish.

Answer (score 7):

The only time I'd seen this stack trace was when I tried calling `CheckForDetailedUpdate()` without setting up the explicit trust before hand. After adding the code below, the update check worked.

```
// Setup the trust level
var deployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
var appId = new ApplicationIdentity(deployment.UpdatedApplicationFullName);
var unrestrictedPerms = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
var appTrust = new ApplicationTrust(appId) {
    DefaultGrantSet = new PolicyStatement(unrestrictedPerms),
    IsApplicationTrustedToRun = true,
    Persist = true
};
ApplicationSecurityManager.UserApplicationTrusts.Add(appTrust);

// Check for update
var info = deployment.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
```

Comment: Just like the OP, I was getting `TrustNotGrantedException`. Your answer allowed me to effectively go one step further by updating the application. But now `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` is `False`. Any straightforward idea or should I start a question?

Answer (score 2):

From this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.trustnotgrantedexception(v=vs.110).aspx) there are two causes. But it seems  `TrustNotGrantedException` is usually raised when a new ClickOnce update has been deployed that uses more privileges than the previous version...

> - The application uses permission elevation and the user denies the request for elevated trust; or
> - The application uses Trusted Application Deployment and the digital certificate used to sign the application is not listed as a trusted publisher on the local machine. **If you have deployed an update to an application, and the update uses more permissions than the previous version, and ClickOnce throws a TrustNotGrantedException, the new version will not install**.

So it makes sense that it would fail to update, because the apps security level has changed since the user last installed it - so they will need to reinstall it.

Comment: Question is how one determines the new deployment has more privileges than the previous - via manifest ? my manifests look exactly the same (including trustInfo element) (excluding obviously version numbers and digestValue elements for dependency assemblies)

Comment: This answer actually helped me. In my case the difference between versions was playing a sound file in a newer version. So I guess, playing a sound file means more privileges. Reinstalling app solved the problem. Thanks @CrazyTim.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and ended up using the [InPlaceHostingManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.inplacehostingmanager?view=netframework-4.7.2) class. It's made for installing or updating a ClickOnce deployment. `GetManifestAsync()` fires the `GetManifestCompleted` event, which gives you the version number. Then you can call `DownloadApplicationAsync()` and handle the `DownloadApplicationCompleted` event. So far this works and no TrustNotGrantedException is thrown.