# WPF Clickonce update failing - Why is Trust Not Granted?

Tags: wpf, clickonce

Trying to get a ClickOnce application to work correctly, but I keep encountering the "Trust Not Granted" exceptions, and I'm not yet seeing why this is happening.

The EXE is signed with a code signing certificate from VeriSign, both by setting the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" option in the Signing tab, as well as implementing the pre-publish approach metioned here: http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/ .  I have verified that the certificate is installed on the client machine correctly.  I have verified that my EXE is signed after the build as well.

I have taken the same approach with setting explicit trusts as this StackOverflow answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16816341/97879

I am presently deploying to a network share, and that is the expected path for updates until we're prepared to take this application to production.

My application can see that there is an update available, but then fails when trying to update.  This happens the same way on both Windows 7 and 8 machines.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you accessing it on the network share via HTTP or UNC share?

Comment: UNC share for now.  We'll switch to HTTP once we get this to work.

Comment: Are you explicitly handling the update mechanism through code or allowing ClickOnce to handle the update check automatically?

Comment: Trying to check for it programmatically.  What we have is an application that is replacing an existing iPad application, and the company is at its end with the App Store and iOS changes.  In order to get past that, we're looking at a "silent" update mechanism that we can use (ClickOnce) in order to keep user required actions to zero.