# TrustNotGrantedException when updating ClickOnce app installed through CD

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, auto-update

We have a ClickOnce app deployed using a CD installer and set up the Update URL (the install URL is empty)

On Windows 7 and Windows 8, the auto-update feature (we use the programmatic approach via System.Deployment) ends up with a TrustNotGrantedException and "User has refused to grant required permissions to the application"

The symptoms are very similar to [Clickonce full trust app update failing with TrustNotGrantedException on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688282/clickonce-full-trust-app-update-failing-with-trustnotgrantedexception-on-windows) but the provided solution does not make any difference.

When using the CD installer, the ClickOnce prompt warning shield is green as local install, is it then not possible to download updates from the web?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947506/clickonce-update-fails-on-net-4-0-app-after-installing-net-4-5
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/82db6a16-d97f-4332-9a3c-b95014f78d2e/clickonce-updates-fail-if-installed-from-disk-under-net-45x?forum=winformssetup

Comment: My workaround was to change the installer to check for internet access and install directly from the website (UpdateURL), which solves the issue for 95% of users.  The TrustNotGrantedException only occurs if an update is available, so when I handle that exception, I pop-up a message asking the user to check the website for new version.  Not an elegant solution, but I ran out of time.

Comment: I've resorted to something similar in the meantime, downloading and immediately running the bootstrapper with the new version. Seems like a work-around though.

Comment: vvondra and XKCD137 - looks like reinstalling is the best solution. See [my post here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39502038/737393).

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and ended up using the [InPlaceHostingManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.inplacehostingmanager?view=netframework-4.7.2). It's made for installing or updating a ClickOnce deployment. `GetManifestAsync()` fires the `GetManifestCompleted` event, which gives you the version number. Then you can call `DownloadApplicationAsync()` and handle the `DownloadApplicationCompleted` event. So far this works and no TrustNotGrantedException is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

We tried workarounds as well, but none resolved all of our issues. If you install your Authenticode certificate (public key only) in the "trusted publishers" certificate store you can then call `ApplicationDeployment.CheckForDetailedUpdate` without the `TrustNotGrantedException`.

This was only a problem for us when starting with CD-install, although we've seen similar issues when changing to a new UpdateLocation. Assuming you haven't changed the default [trust prompt behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308453.aspx), your initial CD-install should have prompted the user (at install time) to elevate the application permissions to FullTrust.

> If the application is configured to check for updates from a Web or network location and a newer version is available, the original installation can receive permissions for the Internet or Intranet zone instead of full-trust permissions. ***To prevent users from being prompted***, a System Administrator can specify a ClickOnce deployment policy that defines a specific application publisher as a trusted source.
>
> (REF: VS2015 [Securing ClickOnce Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76e4d2xw.aspx))

I never found adequate documentation in the [Trusted Application Development Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01daf08f.aspx), but I believe that when you try to go from the MyComputer zone (CD-install) to the Internet zone, the trust manager thinks that the user must be prompted to re-confirm the FullTrust permission elevation. It seems the Trust Prompting only happens when launching the .application file and so you've missed you chance by the time your app is running.

FWIW - our other issues with the workarounds were related to Taskbar pinning on Win10 after switching from a CD-install to a Web-Install. Our behavior was similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/214400/some-taskbar-pinned-icons-are-duplicated-when-an-instance-of-the-application-is) but none of those solutions helped.

Comment: You saved my day. I had TrustNotGrantedException from CD install, but switching to web install it does not complain.