# Manual check for updates with WPF ClickOnce

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I do not want to used the default behavior of ClickOnce, which presents a dialog window, checking for updates, I want to check for update manually

After search on the internet I found:

```
        try
        {
            var deploy = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

            if (deploy.CheckForUpdate())
                MessageBox.Show("There is a new update");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("You using the latest version");

        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e2.ToString());
        }
```

When I install the application and want to check for update I got the error:

> system.deployment.application.trustnotgrantedexception: user has refused to grant required permissions to the application

Could you help please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Right Click on your project. Select Properties. Then go to publish Tab. Click updates. Then uncheck "The application should check for updates".

[image]

I'm not really sure why you are getting that error, but I'm also using the same approach. Checking manually for updates. But my application is deployed on a server. I have this timer that checks for new updates every 15 mins.

Here's how I do it.

```
private void InstallUpdateSyncWithInfo()
    {
        if (!isNewUpdateMessageShown)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
                {
                    ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
                    ad.UpdateCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(ad_UpdateCompleted);
                    //ad_UpdateCompleted is a private method which handles what happens after the update is done
                    UpdateCheckInfo info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
                    if (info.UpdateAvailable)
                    {
                        //You can create a dialog or message that prompts the user that there's an update. Make sure the user knows that your are updating the application.
                        ad.UpdateAsync();//Updates the application asynchronously
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Log();
            }
        }

    }

    void ad_UpdateCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something after the update. Maybe restart the application in order for the update to take effect.

    }
```

**EDIT**

I have updated my answer. You can copy and paste this one and adjust it based on your app needs.

On my previous answer, I'm opening a new window that tells the users that there's an update then have the user choose if he or she wants to update the application.

Comment: .Log() , ad_UpdateCompleted, NewUpdateWindow(), EnableDWMDropShadow, ShowNotifyBaloon, appUpdateTimer not declared. What is the reference should I used ? Can ue gave me a small test app please ?

Comment: We are using some code that is virtually identical to the above for our ClickOnce VSTO add-in for Outlook. Unfortunately, we're getting a `TrustNotGrantedException` indicating that the user refused to grant permissions - but there's never actually a prompt of any kind.

Any suggestions @ljpv14 or @abdulsalam-elsharif?

Comment: @TroyAlford I'm not sure if you've fixed your problem. If not, try checking this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688282/clickonce-full-trust-app-update-failing-with-trustnotgrantedexception-on-windows

Comment: @ljpv14 - thanks SO much! That link helped us figure out the right search terms and we got the problem completely resolved. You rock. :)