# C# ClickOnce Application - User has refused to grant required permissions to the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, clickonce, truststore

I am trying to add automatic updates from sourceforge.com for my C# application using a ClickOnce installer; when I click the "Check for Updates" button that I've added to my application, it successfully checks and sees that there is an update, however when I click "Install Now", I get the following error:

> User has refused to grant required permissions to the application

I saw a similar question on StackOverflow, and I already did what the accepted answer said was the solution, to no avail.

Link to the other StackOverflow question I read: [Clickonce full trust app update failing with TrustNotGrantedException on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688282/clickonce-full-trust-app-update-failing-with-trustnotgrantedexception-on-windows)

It is worth noting that I am on Windows 10, not Windows 8, and that it was working on another Windows 7 computer, but doesn't work on my Windows 10 machine with the same exact code. The other question also mentions that theirs worked on Windows XP and 7, but not 8, however, the solution for Windows 8 that worked for them does not work for Windows 10 for me.

Stack Trace:

```
System.Deployment.Application.TrustNotGrantedException: User has refused to grant required permissions to the application.
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationTrust.RequestTrust(SubscriptionState subState, Boolean isShellVisible, Boolean isUpdate, ActivationContext actCtx, TrustManagerContext tmc)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrustCore(Boolean blocking, TrustParams tp)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrust(TrustParams trustParams)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.Update()
   at Desktop_Beautifier.Form1.update()
   at Desktop_Beautifier.Form1.btnCheckUpdates_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Relevant Code from my Application:

```
    private void btnCheckUpdates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckForUpdateAvailable())
        {
            update();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No updates are available at this time.");
        }
    }
    private bool CheckForUpdateAvailable()
    {
        Uri updateLocation = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation;

        //Used to use the Clickonce API but we've uncovered a pretty serious bug which results in a COMException and the loss of ability
        //to check for updates. So until this is fixed, we're resorting to a very lo-fi way of checking for an update.

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string manifestFile = webClient.DownloadString(updateLocation);

        //We have some garbage info from the file header, presumably because the file is a .application and not .xml
        //Just start from the start of the first tag
        int startOfXml = manifestFile.IndexOfAny(new[] { '<' });
        manifestFile = manifestFile.Substring(startOfXml);

        Version version;

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        //build the xml from the manifest
        doc.LoadXml(manifestFile);

        XmlNodeList nodesList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("assemblyIdentity");
        if (nodesList == null || nodesList.Count <= 0)
        {
            throw new XmlException("Could not read the xml manifest file, which is required to check if an update is available.");
        }

        XmlNode theNode = nodesList[0];
        version = new Version(theNode.Attributes["version"].Value);

        if (version > ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion)
        {
            // update application
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void update()
    {
        UpdatesForm updatesForm = new UpdatesForm();
        DialogResult result = updatesForm.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileIOPermission fp = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
            fp.Assert();

            ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
            try
            {
                var appId = new ApplicationIdentity(ad.UpdatedApplicationFullName); 
                var unrestrictedPerms = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
                var appTrust = new ApplicationTrust(appId)
                {
                    DefaultGrantSet = new PolicyStatement(unrestrictedPerms),
                    IsApplicationTrustedToRun = true,
                    Persist = true
                };
                ApplicationSecurityManager.UserApplicationTrusts.Add(appTrust);

                ad.Update();
                MessageBox.Show("The application has been upgraded, and will now restart.");
                Application.Restart();
            }
            catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the latest version of the application. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde);
                return;
            }
            CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            updatesForm.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might add a link to the SO question you reference in your question, it will help others understand what you've already tried

Comment: @Mick good point, added.

Comment: Hey Mate, I've posted an answer on the other SO question. It might help!

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue when I tried to change the Install/Update url from a http address to https and releasing an update. All existing application would throw a `TrustNotGrantedException` when they tried to install the update. As soon as I reverted the change the error went away.